# Error con ajax y consulta a base de datos con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas, tengo un problema con unas pruebas de ajax que estoy realizando, es sobre un input que por un metodo keyup va enviando consultas a la base de datos, esto con ajax, me deberia retornar en consola un array con los datos de la consulta, y lo hace... el problema viene cuando coloco una letra que no coincide en la base de datos, me devuelve etiquetas html como las siguientes, deberia devolverme un array vacio (lo que esta en rojo hacia arriba es el error, lo de azul es como debería devolver los datos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo el codigo del php y el js, haganme saber si necesitan el html:

```
  AJAX.PHP  
<?php
    include('conect.php');
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    if (!empty($search)) {
        $query = "SELECt * FROM ajax WHERE name LIKE '$search%'";
        $process = mysqli_query($conect, $query);
        if (!$process) {
            die('query error' . mysqli_error($conect));
        }
        while ($register = mysqli_fetch_array($process)) {
            $json[] = array(
                'name' => $register['name'],
                'description' => $register['description'],
                'id' => $register['id']
            );
        }
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonstring;
    }
    ?>
```

AJAX.JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').keyup(()=>{ 
        let search = $('#search').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { search },
            success: function (response) {
                // let tasks = JSON.parse(response)
                // console.log(tasks)
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Por cierto, en el js la la funcion JSON.parse() me devuelve error cuando me devuelven el monton de etiquetas html así que esta ignorado aquí

Comment: Porque te devuelve HTML que no hace parte del error??, estas acaso devolviendo HTML entero del lado del servidor??, debería devolverte solo el json...

Comment: todo funciona... hasta que la query a la db no coincide, me devuelve eso (si te fijas por ahí decia json no definido)

Comment: Muchas gracias Riven, pero hay un detalle, me marca error cuando borro todo y el input esta vacio, es normal?

Comment: En tu caso es normal eso, pero es debido a que solo estas retornando un json si la busqueda no esta vacia, pero en caso de que este vacia, desde el lado de php no estarias retornando nada, tendras que retornar siempre algo, de lo contrario el error que te marca debe ser jquery tratando de parsear algo que no es un json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu variable `json` debe estar declarada fuera de tu ciclo, por que si lo haces dentro de tu ciclo, esta solo existirá dentro de tu ciclo (lo mismo como si usaras `let` en js), así que declárala fuera de tu ciclo:

```
<?php
    include('conect.php');
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    if (!empty($search)) {

        //Aqui debes declarar a tu variable $json.
        $json = [];
        $query = "SELECt * FROM ajax WHERE name LIKE '$search%'";
        $process = mysqli_query($conect, $query);
        if (!$process) {
            die('query error' . mysqli_error($conect));
        }
        while ($register = mysqli_fetch_array($process)) {
            array_push(
               $json,
               array(
                'name' => $register['name'],
                'description' => $register['description'],
                'id' => $register['id']
               )
            );
        }
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonstring;
    }
?>
```

Y bueno... tambien en esta linea para no confundirnos y tampoco confundir a la variable, lo que tu tenias era:

```
$json[] = array(
   'name' => $register['name'],
   'description' => $register['description'],
   'id' => $register['id']
);
```

Y lo cambie a:

```
$json = array(
   'name' => $register['name'],
   'description' => $register['description'],
   'id' => $register['id']
);
```

**Notese que no hay corchetes en $json.**

También obsérvese que tu tenias un ciclo en el cual estabas cargando información, para poder que obtengas toda tu información y tu información no se pierda al reasignar la información, deberás hacer de tu json un array directamente y hacer un push a tu json de la información que estas obteniendo cada vez en el ciclo, de lo contrario la información traída al final por el json será la ultima recibida en el ciclo, entonces afuera del ciclo declaramos tu json como un array:

```
//Aqui debes declarar a tu variable $json.
$json = [];
```

Y dentro del ciclo hacemos esto:

```
array_push(
   $json,
   array(
     'name' => $register['name'],
     'description' => $register['description'],
     'id' => $register['id']
    )
);
```

De esta manera tendrás tu colección entera de información traída por el ciclo en un solo json, la cual podrás luego consultar en el frontend.

Comment: Solo dos correcciones: inicializa `$json = [];` y, dentro del ciclo se van a estar agregando elementos, entonces ahí sí estaba bien la asignación `$json[] = array(...);`

Comment: No es necesario, puedes dejarlo sin inicializar y posteriormente inicializarlo no es necesario especificar que tenga un valor de inicios. aunque si te refieres a esa inicializacion que hace nuestro OP, realmente no sabia que se podia declarar un arreglo tambien asi... pero a el declararlo de esa manera parece funcionarle... asi que decidi omitir ese detalle...

Comment: Es raro, estoy probando y funciona hasta sin declarar en PHP 7.2.14. Pero si dejas solo `$json = array(...);` se va a sobreescribir en cada iteración del ciclo.

Comment: Por supuesto, en eso tienes razon por que el OP, no tuvo en cuenta ese pequeno detalle de que esta sobrescribiendo el mismo json, pero bueno... eso hace parte del codigo del propio OP... no se si depronto el quiera que solucionemos ese detalle... ya que la pregunta es sobre resolver esos errores por pantalla que se ven...

Comment: De hecho, en la pregunta original sí aparecen los corchetes dentro del ciclo.

Comment: Ciertamente no hay corchetes en JSON, pero estás trabajando un array en PHP, ahí sí se necesitan los corchetes para agregar un nuevo elemento, es el equivalente de `json.push(array(...))`

Comment: Si, esos corchetes es lo que decia que al parecer si le funcionan al OP de esa manera, asi que decidí omitir ese detalle y pasarlo por alto, puesto que declarar la variable con el mismo nombre fuera del ciclo va a sobreescribirla, asi que en teoria tendria que ser el mismo resultado...

Comment: Es que en php existe otra forma de declarar arreglos sin usar corchetes... y pues eso de sobreescribir el json es algo que el OP paso por alto... pero es codigo que no modifique, es decir, directamente no cambie a array_push, porque pense que depronto habia algo en especial del porque el op no habia usado array_push... es decir, en esa parte intencionalmente no hago uso de array_push, es solo para arreglar ese error que obtiene el OP en pantalla.

Comment: Declarar array `$json = [];` o `$json = array();` Agregar elemento `$json[] = 'nuevo elemento';` o `array_push($json, 'nuevo elemento');`

Comment: No me haz entendido... me refiero a que no estoy arreglando ese detalle que el OP paso por alto, estoy arreglando es solamente el error que le aparece al OP, ya edito la respuesta y arreglo ese detalle de una vez tambien...

Comment: Compadre, revisa en la pregunta, dentro del ciclo sí están los corchetes y, de hecho, son necesario para agregar todos los registros que arroje la consulta, de lo contrario, se va a sobreescribir en cada iteración y solo va a devolver el último. Pero bueno, esperemos a que haga la prueba quien preguntó y diga si funciona o no.

Comment: Los corchetes no son necesarios si se usa array_push amigo, son necesarios del lado derecho, por que obviamente para hacer un push debe ser un array... pero no son necesarios del lado izquierdo... o la otra forma es usando array(), para crear un array sin usar corchetes...

Comment: Al final lo hiciste con [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) que es lo mismo que `$json[] = array('Elemento1', 'elemento2', 'etc');` pero con menor rendimiento. Lo bueno es que ahora sí va a funcionar.  +1

Comment: Que tonto soy... se me habia olvidado el spread operator por completo, ya entiendo a lo que te referías, gracias Triby me recordaste ese operador xd, si, enrealidad es un buen operador para ese proposito.

Comment: No, no tiene que ver con ese operador, solo era un ejemplo, ya edité el comentario.